# MySQL: Manipulate column data in a query with SELECT *

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to manipulate column data in a query where you do SELECT *?

table

```
id - delivery
1  - 0
2  - 0
3  - 12
```

Something like:

```
SELECT *, IF(delivery = '0', '9') FROM table
```

Or do you have to select the columns individually?

This would be a total mess for me since the actual table has like 40 columns.

EDIT: I didnt make myself clear what i wanted. The result should be:

```
id - delivery
1  - 9
2  - 9
3  - 12
```

Comment: What should be the result of your query?

Comment: all rows should be returned, and the rows with delivery 0 will show as delivery 9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *, case delivery when '0' THEN  '9' ELSE delivery END FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
,

```
Select 
column1, 
column2,
CASE WHEN delivery=0 THEN 9
ELSE delivery
END DELIVERY

from TABLE
```